# How I Can Add SSAS TO Excel Services Application Trusted Data Provider in Share Point 2013?

Tags: excel-services, sql-analysis-services

I use SharePoint 2013 and I want create some Excel Report from my SSAS database.

For configuration my Excel Service, I go to `Central Administration` and `Manage service applications`, then `Excel Services Application` and to `Trusted Data Providers`.

In page Excel Services Application Trusted Data Providers I want add SSAS for a Trusted Data Provider then I "Add Trusted Data Provider".

But what are Provider ID, Provider Type and Description for SSAS?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Provider ID:** MSOLAP or MSOLAP.3 or MSOLAP.4 (depending on your SSAS version. For SQL 2012 it would be .4)

**Provider Type:** : OLE DB

**Description (optional):** Microsoft OLE DB Provider for OLAP Services 10.0

Comment: Then , it show that this setting automatically was configure!